# Check if JTextField contains only letters or numbers

Tags: java, regex, swing, validation, jtextfield

I have a JTextField where the user can type anything. What is a convenient way to check if the String of TextField.getText() does contain letters or numbers only? Basically I just want to avoid any other symbol (e.g. _^$. etc)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider using the String method `matches` which takes a regular expression as an argument and determines whether the string matches the regular expression. For example, alphanumeric can be represented by the regular expression `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` which matches the patter any lower case letter or uppercase letter or number at least 1 time.

Consider the following code:

```
String text = "axc";
boolean match = text.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+");
```

You might want to go through this [Java Tutorial on regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Comment: That is a solution; however, since this test is supposed to be run several times, it is best if you create a `Pattern` out of it ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this
assign the value u get frm the text field to the variable "data"..
and then use that regex to know if it contains letters or numbers and not caharacters

```
    String regex = "[a-zA-Z0-9]+"; 
    String data = "5hekkqhwj57586";
    System.out.println(data.matches(regex));
```